# is.object and the S3 class system

Tags: oop, r, r-s3, r-s4

Using the `class` function allows us to determine the class of an object:

```
> x = 5
> class(x)
[1] "numeric"
```

I also understand that we can use the `is.object` command to determine if an object has a class. However some object types are implicit, that is

```
> is.object(x)
[1] FALSE
```

Would it be correct to state that all variables in R are objects and `is.object` is a test for non-implicit classes only?

Also, how do types fit into this. Naively, I thought that the following piece of code would produce an error:

```
> x = 5
> class(x) = "fake"
> x = X + 1
> x + 1
[1] 6
attr(,"class")
[1] "fake"
```

But `x` still has type "double", still everything still works. Can types be thought of as a superclass that all other objects inherit from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`typeof` returns the type of internal C representation, and it is not used for method dispatch. So strictly speaking you can not think of types as "superclasses".

There are instead **basic classes** (numeric, character, list, function etc) which roughly correspond to the names
returned by `typeof`, but not always (for example type double is of class numeric, special and closure are of class
function, and class data.frame is of type list!).

With S3 and S4 systems you can build non trivial classes using basic classes (but not necessary extending one of those!! example: `setClass("foo", list(a="numeric",b="character")` does not extend any of the **basic classes**).

For objects from these basic classes `is.object` returns `FALSE`. As its documentation says, this function provides
a very fast way to check if the object is of user build S3 or S4 class (i.e. not one of basic classes).

After casting `x` as "fake" your object is formally not of "numeric" class:

```
is(x, "numeric")
#FALSE
```

but it is interpretable as basic "numeric" object:

```
is.numeric(x)
#TRUE
```

And this is why `+` works here. So, internally, as @Richie already said the default method interprets `x` as of
numeric basic class.

This conceptual mess is because of S3 informal treatment of classes. Use S4 instead.

---

correspondence between typeof(.) and basic class(.):

```
                              typeof(.)  class(.)
NULL                          "NULL"     "NULL"
1                             "double"   "numeric"
1:1                           "integer"  "integer"
1i                            "complex"  "complex"
list(1)                       "list"     "list"
data.frame(x=1)               "list"     "data.frame"
pairlist(pi)                  "pairlist" "pairlist"
c                             "special"  "function"
lm                            "closure"  "function"
formals(lm)[[1]]              "symbol"   "name"
formals(lm)[[2]]              "symbol"   "name"
y~x                           "language" "formula"
expression((1))[[1]]          "language" "("
(y~x)[[1]]                    "symbol"   "name"
expression(x <- pi)[[1]][[1]] "symbol"   "name"
```

Comment: S4 introduces its own set of problems.  I don't think it's good to advise to use S4 instead of S3 without knowing more about the problem.

Comment: @hadley In my experience the problems with S4 come mostly from messy and opaque implementation - it is full of internal workarounds and patches. This often causes unexpected results and personally I am also quite tired of that. The system itself mimics Common Lisp Object System which is widely recognized as one of the most flexible and robust object orientations. Besides, the fact that R becomes more and more S4-rish is a good reason to use S4 and not S3.

Answer (score 2):

A partial answer to the first question is found in Chapter 2 of the R language defninition

> R does not provide direct access to
>   the computer’s memory but rather
>   provides a number of specialized data
>   structures we will refer to as
>   objects. These objects are referred to
>   through symbols or variables. In R,
>   however, the symbols are themselves
>   objects and can be manipulated in the
>   same way as any other object.

So, yes, all variables are objects.

`is.object` seems to be more or less equivalent to `function(x) !is.null(attr(x, "class"))` but I'm willing to be proved wrong on that.

As for the second question, I think this is what happens:
Since `x` has class "fake", R looks for a method `+.fake` in the addition but when it doesn't find one, it resorts to the default method.  That default method is based upon underlying C code, which uses `typeof(x)` (or a C equivalent) to determine what should be done. In this case the type of `x` is "integer".